# Processing exception while streaming http response object using Data Buffer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jax-rs, streaming, spring-webflux

Getting error "Unable to find a MessageBodyReader" while writing the response to a file using DataBufferUtils.

My code

```
public class Downloader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client targetClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();

        WebTarget target = targetClient.target("https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-zip-file.zip");

        Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux = (Flux<DataBuffer>) target
                .request()
                .rx(FluxRxInvoker.class).get(DataBuffer.class);

        Path path = Paths.get("file.txt");

        DataBufferUtils.write(dataBufferFlux, path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE).block();
    }
}
```

Error stack trace

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/zip and type class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.SseEventInputImpl
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ClientReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ClientReaderInterceptorContext.java:47)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.getReader(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:133)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:75)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readFrom(ClientResponse.java:217)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:90)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.AbstractBuiltResponse.readEntity(AbstractBuiltResponse.java:262)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.client.SseEventSourceImpl$EventHandler.run(SseEventSourceImpl.java:338)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.client.SseEventSourceScheduler$1.run(SseEventSourceScheduler.java:92)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/zip and type class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.SseEventInputImpl
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ClientReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ClientReaderInterceptorContext.java:47)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.getReader(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:133)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:75)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readFrom(ClientResponse.java:217)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:90)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.AbstractBuiltResponse.readEntity(AbstractBuiltResponse.java:262)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.client.SseEventSourceImpl$EventHandler.run(SseEventSourceImpl.java:338)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.client.SseEventSourceScheduler$1.run(SseEventSourceScheduler.java:92)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
                at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:93)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1663)
                at Downloader.main(Downloader.java:32)
```

Dependencies

```
implementation("org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec:1.0.3.Final") 

implementation("org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-reactor:4.6.0.Final") 

implementation("org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:3.6.2.Final") 

implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.7.1")
```

Thins I have already tried :

```
I have added jackson2 provider as suggested but that didn't work for me.

I also tried registering jackson provider explicitly but that too didn't work for me.

 ResteasyProviderFactory instance= ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
 RegisterBuiltin.register(instance);
 instance.registerProvider(ResteasyJackson2Provider.class);
```

I have referred [Spring Streaming doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs-streaming) for the understanding the concept. I am very new to this.

Any ideas what is causing this issue of unable to find **MessageBodyReader** and how can we fix it?

Edit:

Used custom MessageBodyReader. But now that returns me below error. Not sure how to fix this as I am downloading a file.

```
@Consumes("application/zip")
public class CustomMessageBodyReader
        implements MessageBodyReader<SseEventInputImpl> {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
                              Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == SseEventInputImpl.class;
    }

    @Override
    public SseEventInputImpl readFrom(Class<SseEventInputImpl> type,
                               Type genericType,
                               Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
                               MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
                               InputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SseEventInputImpl.class);
            SseEventInputImpl myBean = (SseEventInputImpl) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller()
                    .unmarshal(entityStream);
            return myBean;
        } catch (JAXBException jaxbException) {
            throw new ProcessingException("Error deserializing a SseEventInputImpl.",
                    jaxbException);
        }
    }
}
```

Error with custom MessageBodyReader

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing a SseEventInputImpl.
        at CustomMessageBodyReader.readFrom(CustomMessageBodyReader.java:41)
        at CustomMessageBodyReader.readFrom(CustomMessageBodyReader.java:17)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:101)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:80)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readFrom(ClientResponse.java:217)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:90)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.AbstractBuiltResponse.readEntity(AbstractBuiltResponse.java:262)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.client.SseEventSourceImpl$EventHandler.run(SseEventSourceImpl.java:338)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.client.SseEventSourceScheduler$1.run(SseEventSourceScheduler.java:92)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: null
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:563)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:204)
        at CustomMessageBodyReader.readFrom(CustomMessageBodyReader.java:38)
        ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:994)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

You can try it out using [Project GitHub link](https://github.com/sunny-shaw/WebClient-API-Playground/blob/download-file/src/main/java/Downloader.java) for understanding the issue better if interested.

Comment: The response looks like it's zipped (application/zip). You need a MessageBodyReader that knows how to handle application/zip. Or get the response as in InputStream and unzip it yourself.

Comment: Similar error happens for content-type text/plain.  Looks like an issue with MessageBodyReader. Not sure exactly what is wrong.

Also, due to some technical limitation, I cannot use InputStream.

Comment: Because there is no reader for text/plain... and for good reason – plain text is not structured. Either take is as a string, InputStream, or create your own reader.You might want to go through Jersey documentation on entity providers

Comment: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html

Comment: I have tried with custom MessageBodyReader but now I am getting  below error 

"Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog"

Not sure how to fix this now as I am downloading a file.

Edited the question with custom MessageBodyReader.  Please suggest if I am still missing something.